# How to enrich the message headers with uri variables or parameters in Spring Integration java dsl

Tags: spring-integration

I'm trying to enrich the headers of the messages coming from an http inbound gateway ;
my uri looks like this:

```
requestMapping.setPathPatterns("/context/{fooId}");
```

But I don't know how to use the setHeaderExpressions method of the HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway to catch the uri variable and put its value in the header.

I have no more success with the .enrichHeaders(...) since this code generates an exception:

```
IntegrationFlows.from(requestNotificationChannel())
  .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("fooId", "#pathVariables.fooId")
```

What is the good way to extract the values from the uri-variables and/or from the parameters ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you missunderstood a bit how `HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway` works or we missed something in the documentaiton.

Each SpEL evaluation is done withing `EvaluationContext` and it is fresh for each component. The `#pathVariables` `EvaluationContext` varialbe is available only from the `HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway` during request processing. Other similar variables from the `request` and available for message building from the `HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway` are:

- `requestAttributes`
- `requestParams`
- `requestHeaders`
- `cookies`
- `matrixVariables`

What I want to say that it doesn't work for regular `.enrichHeaders()` because it uses a new fresh `EvaluationContext` and all those variable aren't available already. That's why `HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway` provides `setHeaderExpressions`. and here is a sample how to use it for you case:

```
private final static SpelExpressionParser PARSER = new SpelExpressionParser();
....
@Bean
public HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway httpInboundGateway() {
     ....
     httpInboundGateway.setHeaderExpressions(Collections.singletonMap("fooId", PARSER.parseExpression("#pathVariables.fooId")));
     ....
}
```

From other side, if your `requestNotificationChannel()` is `DirectChannel`, you don't leave the HTTP Request Thread in the `.enrichHeaders()`, therefore you can do something like this:

```
.enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerFunction("fooId", m ->
                        ((Map<String, String>) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()
                                        .getAttribute(HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE, 0)).get("fooId")))
```